# Is there an escape option for single quotes & apostrophes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, expression, string, escaping

I'm trying to use the Data Defined symbology in QGIS ver 2.2. Some of my data has single quotes/apostrophes.

Since the string must use single quotes, is there an escape option I can use for the field calculator or for the data defined settings field?

So, I'm trying to use something like this:

```
CASE
WHEN "NAME" = 'WILSON'S' THEN '0,75,224'
END
```

How do you build an expression around a string that may have a single quote or apostrophe?

Thanks.
QGIS Valmiera 2.2
Windows 7 - 32 bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the escaping by simply doubling the single quote works for me:

```
CASE
WHEN "NAME" = 'WILSON''S' THEN '0,75,224'
END
```

Double quotes in the field value don't need escaping:

```
CASE
WHEN "NAME" = 'WILSON"S' THEN '0,75,224'
END
```

and I'm not sure if they are allowed in field names. Surely not in shapefiles.

Works at least on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can always mask **every** character, including single or double quotes, by using their ascii-code:

- `char(39)` returns a single quote: `'`
- `char(34)` returns a double quote: `"`

To find the ascii code, simply look for it with `ascii()`: `ascii('a')` returns 97. To find the ascii code for single quotes, enter `ascii('''')` - this returns `39`.

Thus you can also use:

```
CASE
WHEN "NAME" = 'WILSON' || char(39) || 'S' THEN '0,75,224'
END
```

`char` even works for Unicode codes:

- `char(19123)` returns `䪳`, the symbol [coded 19123 in Unicode](https://wutils.com/unicode/19123/encodings).

Comment: Thank you for this. I used it in model builder where I added a string model parameter to PostgreSQL execute and load SQL algorithm. Double quotes did not work there.