# Geometry by expression in QGIS Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, expression

I want to use `Geometry by expression` in a model I'm working on but I couldn't figure out how to pass the layer name parameter. Basically I have two  polygon layers (A and B) and I want to do a feature-by-feature difference using a shared attribute. The expression I have below works outside the modeller.

Inside modeller, since the two layers are intermediate outputs, and not an input, I do not know what to use for the layer name parameter (`layerB`).

```
difference( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'layerB', 'attributeB', attribute($currentfeature, 'attributeA'))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the processing modeller *extremely* challenging to work with, and not as well documented as I'd like it to be. Since my first suggestion didn't work, I have a couple of other suggestions.

*This was my first suggestion, which didn't work:*

> Intermediate output layers are usually called something like
>   `'Toolname of layername'`. Eg, the output of running the `clip` tool
>   on a layer called 'vectorlayer', is probably called something like
>   `'Clip of vectorlayer'`. You can find the exact name of an
>   intermediate output by adding any algorithm that would let you choose
>   the intermediate output as input from a dropdown menu. Make a note of
>   what the intermediate outputs are called, and use that name in your
>   `difference()` expression.

*Suggestion number two:*

I wonder if the issue could be as simple as that the it's expecting a string for 'LayerB', but the string `'Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer'` because has single quotes inside it. So if you used `''Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer''` for 'LayerB', I believe it would be interpreted as three separate strings, with gibberish in between.

- first string: `''`
- gibberish: `Difference`
- second string: `' from algorithm '
- gibberish: `Building_frontbuffer`
- third string: `''`

If this is the issue, you need to escape the single quote characters, so the expression can understand the entire layer name (`'Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer'`) as a single string.

According to this Q&A, [Is there an escape option for single quotes & apostrophes in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95096/is-there-an-escape-option-for-single-quotes-apostrophes-in-qgis), you can just put single quotes around a string with single quotes in it. I wouldn't have thought that would work, but it's worth trying:

`''Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer''`

Note that the string starts and ends with two single quote characters, not one double quote character. (`''` is `'` twice, not `"`)

If that doesn't work, try escaping the single quote with `\`, like this:

`'\'Difference\' from algorithm \'Building_frontbuffer\''`

(Based on suggestions from this Q&A on stackoverflow: [Replacing an apostrophe in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618261/replacing-an-apostrophe-in-a-string).)

*Suggestion number three:*

As a workaround, make the 'difference' output a permanent layer. Define the layer name and filepath with a string input. This way you know exactly what the layer is called, so you can use the correct layer name in the expression.

*Final suggestion:*

If none of the above suggestions works, and you can't find a solution, you just have to end the model at this point. Make the final output of your model a permanent layer from 'Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer'. Put the rest of your steps from the original model into a new model.

Comment: Hi @csk, I've tried your suggestion but I still can't get it to work unfortunately. The name that is shown for the intermediate output is `'Difference' from algorithm 'Building_frontbuffer'`, single quotes included. I've tried different variations of the name including without quotes but still no luck.

Comment: Hi @strythe, I'm sorry my first suggestion didn't work. I updated my answer with a few more suggestions. If any of them works, please let me know which it was, so I can update this to a final answer that might be helpful to others with a similar issue.