# Intersection processing in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, intersection, qgis-modeler

With the graphical modeler in QGIS, how can I update a field called "inters" from layer "a" by setting the values to 'yes' or 'no'. Values are determined on the intersection of another input layer "b".
I used a string based on the overlay_intersects function, both as a "value" or "pre-calculated value" but it doesn't work:

[image]

I add a screen to clarify my test by using "rename a layer":

[image]

The model gives me an error about the expression used. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, what is the expression used in update field algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `Field Calculator` Algorithm, use this expression to update the field: `overlay_intersects ('b')`, where `b` is the layer name. See screenshot, where the output is labeled with the content of the updated `inters` field:

[image]

---

In case you want to use an output of a processing algorithm as input, instead of the layer name, use the *variable* of the algorithm: QGIS automatically adds a varibale with the algorithm's name and the suffix `_OUTOUT` - here, the variable's name to use is `@This_is_my_buffer_algorithm_OUTPUT`, based on my name `This_is_my_buffer_algorithm` I gave to the buffer algorithm and the `@` character that indicates a variable.

In the screenshot below, I used a buffer algorithm, based on a point layer, to create a polygon layer and then I test on another layer called `a` if it intersects with this buffer layer:

[image]

Comment: If i use directly a layer loaded in the layer panel, this expression is ok; but my problem happens when i should use the output of a processing algorithm as input. I don't know how declare this in the expression. Thanks!

Comment: Add a rename layer algorithm to the model, rename the layer and use this as input.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421142/88814

Comment: I renamed (with the rename layer algorithm) the buffer as 'buf', i checked the dependence and i used the expression overlay_intersects ('buf') as a value in the field calculator but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure. Can you share the project/model

Comment: See updated answer for how to proceed.